# z-index issue CSS

Tags: css, z-index

I have a container and dynamically generated div in the container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay">
</div>
<div id="cont">
    <div id="e1">
        Some
    </div>
    <div id="e2">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cont{
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    left:20%;
    z-index:999;
    color:#a8a8a8;
}
#overlay{
    position:fixed;
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    opacity: 0.5;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
#e2{
    z-index:1001;
}
```

**Check this jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/UkbXU/

I have an overlay with z-index 1000 and background rgba(0,0,0,0.5) and the photo container is behind overlay i want only one element to be above overlay, that is with z-index 1001. There are other elements in the container, i do this to show element highlighted effect. But creating a class with z-index: 1001 does'nt bring the element above overlay.

How can i set the z-index of one element to be greater than container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to move the overlay-div into the content-div:

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="overlay"></div>

    <div id="e1">
        Some
    </div>
    <div id="e2">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

and position #e2 have to set to relative. See http://jsfiddle.net/UkbXU/10/

Otherwise it is impossible, because #cont and #overlay are both creating new stacking contexts. These couldn't be merged again.

Comment: yes that's good but if the #cont is e.g. a widget in a sidebar then overlay won't be accross the whole screen only for the widget area or?

Comment: #overlay takes up the whole screen (as defined in CSS width/height/position). But if it lays over the whole page depends on #cont's own position within the stacking context of the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#e2{
    z-index:1001;
    position: absolute;
}
```

It should make the trick.

If not try:

```
#e2{
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0px; //you can change that
    left: 0px; //you can change that
}
```

If it is still not working, well probably some javascript is setting bigger z-indes tahn 9999 to #overlay.

Comment: you need to change #cont z-index to more then overlay identifier. What are you trying to make?

Comment: if changing z-index to #cont then it works but i only want to show only one content to be above #overlay

Comment: You need to do it using javascript. get the content div and put it before overlay again or something like that. Are you doing it in some gallery mode or to show some error?